# How to make a home media/file server with Ubuntu sever, next to Ubuntu 12LTS

Tags: dual-boot, media

So I'm a complete newbie. I have a PC with Ubuntu 12LTS. I would like to share files and media files with my family members in a local network (including a Sony TV).

What about partitioning (swap)? Will a dual boot Ubuntu 12 desktop and Ubuntu 13 server give problems? What are the steps to follow, what are the hot spots during the installation, what kind of file servers, media servers do I need, what about security?

All input wellcomed.

Comment: Why do you need two OS? And when you say you want to share media files, do you mean you need to run a media server and access through DLNA? I'm almost sure that Sony TVs work with DLNA. Would [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) be sufficient?

Comment: thank you Dan, that might do the trick for the media files. I start up "sudo mediatomb" on the terminal and then mediatomb finds the files on the HD. Just need to buy a a cable to connect the TV to the router to test it.

Comment: The sony TV does not accept an update of the server list. All ideas wellcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup Serviio media server on your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tested it with my Sony TV and it was OK. Here's a link to a step by step [guide](http://www.linuxmediaserver.net/digital-media/ubuntu-serviio/).